# Copy/Paste results

Tags: vba, excel

I got the following code, which is supposed to

1) Search for my word, copy and paste the entire row that contains the word into new sheet

2) Search for a word after the 1st, then copy and paste that entire row beside the contents of 1) in the new sheet.

Could someone take a look, I am having trouble actually getting the results, there is no error I am getting. So I assume it is the whole copy and paste to my new sheet name. However i am not 100% sure.

```
Sub stack()

    Dim OSheet As String
    Dim NSheet As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LRow As Integer
    Dim NSLRow As Integer

    OSheet = "Sheet1" 'Old Sheet Name
    NSheet = "Sheet7" 'New Sheet Name

    LRow = Sheets(OSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row in Old Sheet

    Sheets(OSheet).Activate

    For i = 2 To LRow
         'Finds last row in the New Sheet
        If Sheets(NSheet).Cells(2, 1) = "" Then
            NSLRow = 1
        Else
            NSLRow = Sheets(NSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        End If

         'If cell has "First Name then..."
      Dim StrX As String
    If InStr(LCase(Cells(i, 1)), LCase("stack:")) Then
        StrX = Range(Cells(NSLRow + 1, 1), Cells(NSLRow + 1, 6)).Address
        Sheets(NSheet).Range(StrX).Value = Range(StrX).Value
    ElseIf InStr(LCase(Cells(i, 1)), LCase("overflow:")) Then
        StrX = Range(Cells(NSLRow + 1, 7), Cells(NSLRow + 1, 8)).Address
        Sheets(NSheet).Range(StrX).Value = Range(StrX).Value
    End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

EDIT, Expected result:

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNrzZ.jpg

EDIT, updated code with some fixes you guys mentioned.

```
Sub stackv2()
     'added Sheets(OSheets)to Range Cells
    Dim OSheet As String
    Dim NSheet As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LRow As Integer
    Dim NSLRow As Integer

    OSheet = "Sheet1" 'Old Sheet Name
    NSheet = "Sheet7" 'New Sheet Name

    LRow = Sheets(OSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row in Old Sheet

    Sheets(OSheet).Activate

    For i = 2 To LRow
         'Finds last row in the New Sheet
        If Sheets(NSheet).Cells(2, 1) = "" Then
            NSLRow = 1
        Else
            NSLRow = Sheets(NSheet).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        End If

         'If cell has "First Name then..."
      Dim StrX As String
    If InStr(LCase(Cells(i, 1)), LCase("first name")) Then
        StrX = Sheets(OSheet).Range(Sheets(OSheet).Cells(NSLRow + 1, 1), Sheets(OSheet).Cells(NSLRow + 1, 6)).Address
        Sheets(NSheet).Range(StrX).Value = Range(StrX).Value
    ElseIf InStr(LCase(Cells(i, 1)), LCase("last name")) Then
        StrX = Sheets(OSheet).Range(Sheets(OSheet).Cells(NSLRow + 1, 7), Sheets(OSheet).Cells(NSLRow + 1, 8)).Address
        Sheets(NSheet).Range(StrX).Value = Range(StrX).Value
    End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: `StrX = Range(Cells(NSLRow + 1, 1), Cells(NSLRow + 1, 6)).Address` You haven't determined what sheet

Comment: he references the sheet in the next line, that was my 1st thought

Comment: @Nathan_Sav So? Doesn't mean Excel will treat everything around as that sheet. He still has several Range and Cell calls that do not explicitly name a sheet. Nobody knows what those are referencing. It might be useful if OP put a breakpoint on the `If Instr...` line to check values of `Cells(i,1)` and `NSLRow`.

Comment: *I am having trouble actually getting the results* - what results do you expect and what results do you get? A screen shot of expected versus actual results may help us help you better.

Comment: Hi the results I expect are  almost like a transpose: 
A1, First name , A2 Last name, **Result:** A1 First Name, B1, Last Name.  However sometimes they may not be a last name. Thus it must be able to skip that and go to A2 and start with first name again. Is this clearer?

Comment: To add to @MarkBalhoff's comment, specify the sheets each time you use `Range(Cells(),Cells())` to remove any ambiguity: `StrX = OSheet.Range(OSheet.Cells(NSLRow + 1, 7), OSheet.Cells(NSLRow + 1, 8)).Address`. (I'm assuming you want to use `OSheet`'s range...)

Comment: Hi all, I added a picture of the expected result, except the result will occur on another page.

Comment: Does the picture represent your data? Why do you use a range of six columns then? (StrX = Range(Cells(NSLRow + 1, 1), Cells(NSLRow + 1, 6)).Address)

Comment: @BruceWayne, I added OSheet infront of my range cells and get 'invalid qualifier'

Comment: You'd have to add `Sheets(oSheet)`, since `oSheet` is a string, not an object.

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst , no its just a sample. It should be Entire.Row actually :( . But usually I only need about 6 columns or less pasted.

Comment: @BruceWayne was writing it as if OSheet is a Worksheet variable. Yours is a string so Sheets(oSheet)

Comment: @DavidZemens Hi David, I added sheets to every Osheet, still no results, ill post updated code.

Comment: Nothing? Are you sure you are looking in the right place? I copied your updated code into a VBA module and put three rows of names in column B and either "first name" or "last name" in column A. After running the macro both Column A and B were copied over to the other sheet. At least the copy appears to be happening on my end.

Comment: I still don't understand what your actual results look like at the moment.

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst , my results arent the way i expected, it doesnt take all the data over. and they are still in the same format.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff , It seems to work but its not in the format I would like from the picture I posted above

Comment: I'm confused as to what part of your code you thought would perform the transposition. Have you not yet tried to implement that part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for your example:

```
    Sub stackv2()

    Dim OSheet As Worksheet
    Dim NSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As long
    Dim LRow As long
    Dim NSLRow As Long
    Dim cpyClm As Long

    Set OSheet = Sheets("Sheet1") 'change to your Old Sheet Name
    Set NSheet = Sheets("Sheet7") 'change to your New Sheet Name
    cpyClm = 1 'change this to the number columns desired

    'Finds last row in the New Sheet
    NSLRow = NSheet.Cells(NSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With OSheet
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row in Old Sheet

        For i = 2 To LRow

            'If cell has "First Name then..."

            If InStr(LCase(.Cells(i, 1)), LCase("first name")) Then
                NSLRow = NSLRow + 1 'moves to new row every time this is true.
                NSheet.Cells(NSLRow, 1).Resize(, cpyClm).Value = .Cells(i, "A").Resize(, cpyClm).Value
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(Cells(i, 1)), LCase("last name")) Then
                NSheet.Cells(NSLRow, 1 + cpyClm).Resize(, cpyClm).Value = .Cells(i, "A").Resize(, cpyClm).Value
            ElseIf InStr(LCase(Cells(i, 1)), LCase("middle name")) Then
                NSheet.Cells(NSLRow, 1 + (cpyClm * 2)).Resize(, cpyClm).Value = .Cells(i, "A").Resize(, cpyClm).Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

But because we don't know what your true data looks like I put the ability to change the number of columns to copy.  Also since your example does not include column A, and your explanation wants it you will need to change the column in the cells to 1 instead of 2

If this does not work or help you figure out how to adjust it on your own, you will need to post an actual representation of your data and desired output.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I am sorry for the confusion.  Where in this code can I change the columns to copy? Which parts in your explanation did you mean?

Comment: @Ladiesman191 I changed it for you, the only thing you need to change is the number of columns you wish to copy.  Change the line`cpyClm = 1` to what ever number you want.

Comment: so 1=a, 2=b?  yes it did. What did you change from your original answer? I used the original answer and that worked.

Comment: yes 1 = first column or column A, 2 = second column or column B

Comment: does this number refer to the amount of columns being copied or the ones being pasted?

Comment: the variable `cpyClm` refers to # of columns to be copied, and is also used to space the pasting.  so if cpyclm is 6 it will copy 6 columns and in the first if past it in the (1)st column, in the second if statement it will move over to the (1 + 6)th column to paste.  In the third it moves over to the (1 + (6 * 2))th column.  This way no mater what `cpyClm` equals it will paste it correctly.  If you want a forth if you will need to multiply cpyClm by 3 and add 1 to get it to go to the correct place.

Comment: So add 4th criteria would be the same just change cpyclm to * 3,  where do I add the 1?

Comment: Sorry to bother you Scott, but how would you change the column extracting or copying the data from? instead of it being col A.

Comment: @Ladiesman191 I modified the code slightly,  You can now see where it refers to column A,  Change the `"A"` to what ever column you want like `"B"`

Comment: thanks Scott, also when it searches a name ex 'first name', does it search every column or just in column A?

Comment: Column A only. that is what the 1 in `InStr(LCase(.Cells(i, 1))` dictates.  Row i column 1.  Since column A is the first column that is what is being searched.